# BokehJS + React: "Module not found: Can't resolve 'core/bokeh_events'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bokeh, create-react-app, bokehjs

I've installed BokehJs (0.13.0) as a dependency in a create-react-application.  It appears to install just fine, but once I try to require it into a component, I just get this error message:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'core/bokeh_events' in '/Users/myComputer/me/myProject/rootFolder/node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/tree'`

versioning back to earlier releases didn't seem to help, or change what error message I got.  the file core/bokeh_events looks to be where it should be in the node modules, so I can't fathom what could be stopping it from resolving.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a work-around!  Instead of using BokehJS, I just used regular python bokeh, and put the output files in the react app's public folder. No muss, no fuss.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Are you embedding Bokeh into the react view? Thanks

Comment: yes, precisely -- i was using react to construct a page view (in this case, an interactive article), where several of the visuals were constructed using bokeh.  so instead of trying to integrate bokeh directly into the javascript, i simply iframed them in.